# Stuck at running an instance of Postgres via docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: qQmhGTYnBEqfokY3p64x
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: HydJ47qr4F7XqsFhcTsL
      POSTGRES_DB: db

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And when I run it, and I go to `localhost:8080`, choose `PostgreSQL` and set `db` as the default database, and use that use/pass, I get this error:

> Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "qQmhGTYnBEqfokY3p64x"

And from the docker log, I get:

> db_1       | 2023-09-10 13:09:20.373 UTC [33] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "qQmhGTYnBEqfokY3p64x"
> db_1       | 2023-09-10 13:09:20.373 UTC [33] DETAIL:  Role "qQmhGTYnBEqfokY3p64x" does not exist.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Hasan, if the user, and password are the real user and password, please anonymize them now. Also, why are you combining MariaDB and PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Uberhumus, those are fake username passwords. Thank you for mentioning and helping. I updated the question, I use `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, I can log in without any problem from adminer with the given user/pass after starting the compose services from the above file.

Comment: @Zeitounator, after restarting my linux, it worked. Maybe there was a problem with the docker itself.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:10.5
        restart: always
        environment: 
          - POSTGRES_USER=user
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        ports:
          - '5438:5432'
        volumes:
          - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
          - ./sql/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
          - ./sql/fill_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fill_tables.sql
```

You should create two scripts,to create and fill tables at your entrypoint.